# Objective C: Extend From Different Classes

Tags: objective-c, inheritance

I want to extend my `ViewController` from `MKNetworkEngine` class but I have already extended it from `UIViewController` class. How can I extend them both?
Here's my code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
#import "MKNetworkKit.h"

@interface ViewController : MKNetworkEngine UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why inherit? Why not just hold an instance in a property?

Comment: +1 for Wain. Set it up so controller has a MKNetworkEngine rather than being a MKNetworkEngine.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Multiple inheritance is not supported in Objective-C. Composition is preferred over inheritance.

What you can do is have a reference to an object of a different class in you object and make calls to that.